# Снова вопрос про обстоятельства места

Tags: пунктуация

Ну и еще один вопрос про обстоятельства: запятая нужна только одна? Т. к. в лесу и на берегу  - это одно обстоятельство (в лесу, который на берегу).

…расположенного в 12 километрах от города (,) в лиственном лесу на берегу созданного необъятного Обского водохранилища…

Comment: Alenka, формулируйте вопросы без "ещё один" и проч. Через какое-то время они перемешаются так, что никаких "еще одних" не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...расположенного в 12 километрах от города, в лиственном лесу на берегу созданного необъятного Обского водохранилища…

Это неоднородные обстоятельства (в лесу на берегу), еще одна запятая не нужна.

Замечание

Второе обстоятельство плохо читается, слово "созданного" кажется лишним.